# Can I configure things to be automatically required by the Clojure REPL?

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

There are some functions which are quite general and I'd like to have them available in the REPL at all times, no matter what namespace I'm currently switch to.

Is there a way to configure `lein repl` to automatically require some things so that they're globally available? The alternative would be to invoke something like `(use 'clojure.tools.trace)`.

Comment: you might be interested in approach used by vinyasa https://github.com/zcaudate/vinyasa#installation  .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Leiningen 2.x supports `:repl-options` to change the way your REPL behaves, [including `:init` hook](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/sample.project.clj#L343-L345). Leiningen will run this hook when first opening a REPL, so it'll only affect your `:main` namespace.

Here is an example of using this option:

```clj
  :repl-options { :init (require '[criterium.core
                                    :refer [bench quick-bench]])}
```

You could set your `:repl-options` locally for each project in a corresponding `project.clj` file, or globally, by putting it into your `~/.lein/profiles.clj` file:

```clj
{:user {:repl-options {:init (...)}}}
```